# How to add a tab bar item to UITabBarController without a view controller?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

In my iPad app, I have a UITabBarController at the bottom with a bunch of view controllers associated to a bunch of tabs. I would like to have a tab that shows a pop over when the tab is touched. I know how to use the UIPopoverController, but I don't know how to add a tab to a UITabBarController without giving the tab bar controller a UIViewController.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks.

Here is the code that I have to show the pop over. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405350/how-can-i-have-a-popover-come-from-a-tab-instead-of-a-view))

```
CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.bounds.size.height;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tabBarHeight, tabBarHeight);
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect 
    inView:self.tabBarController.tabBar 
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to do this (it's pretty nonstandard UI...), then you could add an empty view controller, but in your tab bar delegate implement

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

And return `NO` for that view controller (so it doesn't get selected) but instead show your popover.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to select the tab so that it is highlighted, but not show the fake view controller?

Comment: Hm, that will be harder. Perhaps you should use your own UITabBar (not connected to a UITabBarController).

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use my own UITabBar. It works, but the more tab button will not be automatically created.